# How to perform segmentation on complex images like rocks (in c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to perform segmentation on a picture of rocks (I've attached a sample). The end goal is to find the approximate rock area (Not sure if the required method is image segmentation).

I have tried several algorithms:

- Texture segmentation does not help as all the rocks are similar.
- I can get the edges with quite a lot of error. Due to shadows. Although possible to use.

Here is an example of input image (you can ignore the basketball): 
[image: Sample image containing rocks]

Please be specific as possible. Considering the complexity of the topic, I'm kind of new.

Comment: What do you mean by the area of the rocks ? On this image it's just the whole picture area.

Comment: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~szheng/crfasrnndemo or http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/ trained with your data should solve the problem.

Comment: I processed your image and got the following result, if its word, I can share the code. http://imgur.com/a/o2Gic

Comment: @Yves Area of the rock that is facing the camera. Assuming that the distance of the camera to the rocks is know. You can find the area of the rock surface.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I'll try that. Though It seems that it mostly performs object detection.

Comment: @Hesper That is pretty much what i get using my edge detection technique and it is doing ok. Though What I need is a closed shape (segmented shapes). Ideally each segmented shape in the image should be a rock which then helps me to find the area.

Comment: @EhsanAb: if you have enough with 2D area, then ImageWidth x ImageHeight. If you want the surface of the individual rocks with some accuracy, drop it, you can't with 2D vision.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed that is true. I will add either a second camera or a Laser scanner later one. Though at the moment, I just want to have some sort of segmentation (even 70% error is fine).

Comment: You can't segment this 2D image. Even a human woud make many mistakes. Maybe by finding the strong edges and mesuring statistics of intercept segment lengths you can find some relation to the area distribution. Maybe some method from geostatistics ?

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'll read about geostatistics.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the links, above mostly for objects segmentation. May be not good for separating stones. Check also this link: http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/ see video, solved task looks similar to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly blurring the image and applying an image segmentation method like watershed can more-or-less solve the question. But as the rock boundaries similar to the texture of the rocks themselves, this won't be an easy task. I would suggest the following:

- If you do not need high accuracy, experiment with the above methods and measure the expected error with some manually annotated images.
- If accuracy is very important and you can ask for user help, create a user interface where the user can place a marker over every rock. Then use a watershed variant starting from these markers (also called seed points) to perform seeded segmentation. (The watershed implementation in OpenCV can do that.)

Comment: Thank you Kristof, i'll try that.